# bootstrap navbar collapse not working

Tags: css, bootstrap

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div *ngIf="_user.logged" class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2"
    id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Incluir Proveedor</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Crear Línea</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Agregar Claves</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">PDF</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div [ngClass]="{'mx-auto order-0': _user.logged}">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" [routerLink]="['/home']">
      <img src="../assets/image/simbavector.svg" width="30" height="30"
        class="d-inline-block align-top bg-light rounded">
      Catalogo
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="_user.logged" class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2 d-md-flex justify-content-end"
    id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-link btn" (click)="logOut()">
        Salir <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tengo este navbar y la idea es que se comporte como un navbar común

se divide en tres secciones, la primera para mostrar las opciones
la segunda es el titulo que se ajusta al inicio y desaparece la primera
la última son para botones de la página

[image: test]

Y en la prueba al hacer click en el botón si colapsa, pero al volver a dar click no se contrae. también ¿cómo se podría hacer que no empuje el contenido debajo?

Uso Bootstrap 5

Y uso Angular 12.1.1

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

las librerías agregadas

[image: test2]

Y así se ve cuando no tiene que colapsar

Comment: @Excorpion entiendo porque lo dices, pero el navbar funciona, lo único que falla es la parte del collapse

Comment: Para ello por favor agrega la seccion completa de html, body y headers, puedes censurar lo que no se necesite. Pero necesitas crear un [mre] del error.

Comment: @Excorpion debo decir que uso Angular, tengo agregado en el Angular.json

Comment: @Excorpion ya lo agregué